# Disable Primary Key in Sequelize JS

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

Is there a way to disable the automatic generated primary key inside Sequelize JS?

We create our tables inside PostgreSQL using Sequelize's sync method. But we've a problem with our junction tables.... We don't want a primary key in our junction table, but Sequelize generates one automatically if we don't specify one our selves. I can specify a primary key on all columns, but that's not the best way to do it....

Anyone who knows how to disable primary keys inside Sequelize JS?

Comment: where you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: Well we don't use the sync method anymore. We create new tables and edit them by using the migrations of Sequelize. So after every deployment we directly deploy new changes for our DB. 
And in our models we use composite primary keys for the junction tables. So just add ```primaryKey: true``` to multiple columns, whose combination makes them unique. So the ```users``` table has an column ```id``` as primary key, ```books``` has an column ```id``` as primary key. But ```user_books``` (= junction table) has 2 primary keys: ```user_id```  and ```book_id``` Not how we want it, but works best.

Comment: Thanks so much, i was struggling with the same since yesterday and did not find a solution, Thanks again i will go your way

Answer (score 5):

```
Model.removeAttribute("id");
```

More documentation [removeAttribute](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-removeAttribute)

Comment: Here is an example of how we tell sequalize to avoid automatic generating of 'id' field.
```const MyTable = db.define('mytable', {
    name: DataTypes.TEXT,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    active: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
});
TimeStarPayType.removeAttribute('id');```

Here is the link to work with legacy tables.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/legacy.html